# Jquery CLONE table row issues

Tags: jquery, clone

I've a couple of small queries with some script I've used in the past.

Previously it worked well to clone a table row and delete a selected row.

But since upgrading to Jquery 3.1.0 it has stopped working.

```
$(function() {
    $('#submitBtm').click(function() {
        var $newRow = $('#TemplateRow').clone(true).removeAttr('id');
        $newRow.find('#Site').val(''); $newRow.find('#Location').val('');
        $newRow.find('*').andSelf().removeAttr('id').removeAttr('disabled');

        $('#cloneTable tr:last').before($newRow);
        return false;
    });

    $('#cloneTable').delegate('.deleteRow:not(#TemplateRow .deleteRow)', 'click', function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

I've googled and found the issue is due to `andSelf()`  If I remove the line with that in then the script works.

Can anyone advise what that line does ?

Also each TR has a unique `data-val` eg:

```
        <tr id="TemplateRow" data-val='123456'>
```

When I Add (clone) a new row I'd like to give it a unique data-val. At this point what it is doesn't matter as long as it's unique.

I thought I'd use the epoch time stamp so tried the following to set the data-val:

```
var milliseconds = (new Date).getTime();
$newRow.find('[data-val]').val(milliseconds);
```

But the cloned row still has 123456, can any one help with that?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/andSelf says what it does, when it was deprecated (ages ago), when it was removed (v3), and what to use instead.

Comment: Thanks - I've read that and how `addBack` is the replacement. But it fails if I change the script to use that.  `$newRow.find(....).andBack().` is not a function.

Comment: It's [`addBack`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/), not `andBack`, and absolutely exists on the return value of `find`. I suggest spending a bit more time reading the documentation.

Comment: Thanks.. I miss typed it so it was causing the error.